# Vba Excel from Internet Explorer to Selenium, converting code

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox

I have this VBA code that was working fine until today, now Internet explorer is not opening the url in the right way (I think it is too old)

```
Sub QUERYFUT()
On Error Resume Next
'query web future
Sheets("Foglio1").Activate
myURL = "https://www.barchart.com/futures/quotes/VI*0/futures-prices?timeFrame=daily"
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With IE
    .navigate myURL
    .Visible = True
    Do While .Busy: DoEvents: Loop    'Attesa not busy
    Do While .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop 'Attesa documento
End With
myStart = Timer  
Do
    DoEvents
    If Timer > myStart + 5 Or Timer < myStart Then Exit Do
Loop
Sheets("Foglio1").Select
Set myColl = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")
With myColl(0)
    For Each trtr In .Rows
        For Each tdtd In trtr.Cells
            'If J = 56 Then Exit For
            Cells(i + 1, J + 1) = tdtd.innerText
            J = J + 1
        Next tdtd
        i = i + 1: J = 0
DoEvents
    Next trtr
i = i + 1
End With
IE.Quit
Set IE = Nothing
```

And I'm trying to make it working with selenium and chrome (firefox would be fine too)

```
Option Explicit
Private cd As Selenium.ChromeDriver
Sub QUERYFUT()
On Error Resume Next
Sheets("Foglio1").Activate
Set cd = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
cd.Start
cd.Get "https://www.barchart.com/futures/quotes/VI*0/futures-prices?timeFrame=daily"

'Leggi le tabelle SUL FOGLIO ATTIVO
Sheets("Foglio1").Select
Dim myColl As Selenium.WebElements
Dim trtr As Selenium.WebElement
Dim tdtd As Selenium.WebElement
Dim J as Long
Dim i as Long
Set myColl = cd.FindElementsByTag("TABLE")
With myColl(0)
    For Each trtr In .Rows
        For Each tdtd In trtr.Cells
            'If J = 56 Then Exit For
            Cells(i + 1, J + 1) = tdtd.innerText
            J = J + 1
        Next tdtd
        i = i + 1: J = 0
    Next trtr
i = i + 1
End With
End Sub
```

It's my first time working with Selenium and Chrome, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: So why tag firefox?

Comment: I dont know if it is possible to do with firefox in a better/simple way

Comment: So did you consider tagging Safari?

Comment: It is possible to use only 5 tag and I dont know if Selenium works with Safari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of that unclosed `On Error Resume Next` which is masking all potential errors.

At first glance I can see you trying to use methods of `MSHTML.HTMLTable` on a `WebElement`, which won't work.

Use the in-built methods e.g. `Dim myColl As Selenium.Table` then use the `.ToExcel` method to write out the table to a specified range in one go.

[image]

---

FireFox is no longer supported (not since a very old version) so forget about that. You do have a choice of several other browsers but Chrome should be good enough.

Make sure your ChromeDriver and Chrome browser versions are [compatible](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads).